# Changing Windows display language from Japanese to English

Tags: language, acer-aspire, windows-10-v1803, japanese

So I changed my laptop's language to be in Japanese in order to use a program called [UTAU](https://utau.fandom.com/wiki/UTAU_wiki) (if you don't know what UTAU is, it is a Japanese singing synthesizer application that's similar to the Vocaloid software).

I did this because I saw it in a tutorial video from YouTube. I then decided that it was too much work for me to use the program, at least for now, so I deleted it and changed most of my system back to English, but for some reason the date on the welcome screen is stuck in **Japanese**.

I went to Region > Administrative > Copy settings and saw that it was set to Japanese for Welcome screen and New user accounts. I can't find a way to change it back.

I feel like I've tried everything. I looked up this issue on Google and I kept seeing the "override for windows display language" option pop up a lot in the search results, but I can't find this option on my laptop. Does anybody have an idea for what I can do to change it back to English?

My laptop is a Windows 10 Home Version 1803 Acer Aspire E15, for those who were wondering.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "Copy settings" window is literally how you change these values.

[image]

Your own settings under "Current user" are already in English (US). Therefore it should be enough to select both checkboxes under "Copy your current settings to..." and confirm with 'OK'.

---

If this doesn't work, the "Welcome Screen" settings are at `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` in the Registry. It should be possible to export your settings from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` into a .reg file using RegEdit, edit the file to replace `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` with `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT`, and import it again.

To do the same for "New user accounts", it is necessary to "load" C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT through RegEdit first.

Some examples can be found in [this Technet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6a21b20a-4d04-460a-b672-968de78c6646/command-line-tools-to-completely-change-regioninput-language-for-default-user-and-welcome-screen?forum=winservergen).